# How to list product info with wmic?

Tags: batch-file, wmic

I already tried several examples found on web about how list some info of a product using `wmic` but until now withou sucess.

My last attempt that can be see below was based on code of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30790561/get-product-name-from-wmic-for-a-variable-in-batch), but comes a error saying:

> No Instance(s) Available

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=1 delims==" %%a in (
     'wmic product where "Name like 'Java'" get name /format:table'
) do (
   for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ("%%a") do  set PROD=%%a
) 
echo %PROD%

pause
```

There is solution to this?

Comment: I suppose the first question should be "are you sure Java is actually installed?"

Comment: @SomethingDark, Yes!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use some wildcard(s) with `like` [WQL operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394606(v=vs.85).aspx) to determine whether or not a given character string matches a specified pattern, e.g. as follows:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "usebackq skip=1 delims==" %%a in (
    `wmic product where "Name like 'Java%%'" get name /format:table`
) do (
   for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ("%%a") do  (
     set "PROD=%%~#"
     echo !PROD!
   )
)
echo PROD (final value)=%PROD%
```

**Sample output**:

```
Java 8 Update 151
Java 8 Update 151 (64-bit)
Java Auto Updater
PROD (final value)=Java Auto Updater
```

See also https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/07/13/use-the-like-operator-to-simplify-your-wql-queries/